# PHP:HTML / $_POST FORM

Tags: php, html, forms

I have this:

```
   <form action="profiles.php" method="POST" name="SearchSimple" id="SearchSimple" >
<input name="search" id="s" style="width: 150px;" type="text">
        <a style="display: inline-block; width: 100px; font-weight: bold; cursor: pointer;" id="submitSearchSimple">Search </a>
            <script>
                        $('#submitSearchSimple').click(function() {
    javascript:document.SearchSimple.submit();
        });
            </script>
</form>
```

It submits fine although when i do

```
if($_POST["submitSearchSimple"] && isset($_POST["submitSearchSimple"])) {
echo $_POST["s"] . " -TEST";
}
```

It doesnt show.. I get nothing

Comment: `if ($_POST["submitSearchSimple"] && isset($_POST["submitSearchSimple"]))` needs to be the other way around. You test for `isset` to figure out if the variable exists in the first place, to avoid trying to access a variable that doesn't exist (which results in a warning). Hence: `if (isset($foo) && $foo)` to test for "if variable exists and variable is true-ish". Which BTW is the same as `if (!empty($foo))`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In PHP, POST variables work only for INPUT elements, SELECT elements & that too in a FORM, only when the form is submitted. Also you need to specify the "name" attribute of those elements to be catched / used by the POST superglobal array variable.

```
In your case, you can simply do this:-
if(isset($_POST["search"]) && !empty($_POST["search"])) {
    echo $_POST["search"] . " -TEST";
}
```

Always remember that there is one major difference in PHP with JavaScript / jQuery. In JavaScript / jQuery, you can use either the "id" attribute or the "name" attribute to validate / manipulate the fields. But in PHP, it is always the "name" attribute of the field that is important, so be careful in doing those.

Hope it helps.

Comment: `isset($_POST["search"]) && !empty($_POST["search"])` is halfway redundant. You can skip the `isset` check.

Comment: @deceze - There are specific situations where the "`isset`" check is necessary instead of just providing the variable in the "`if`" condition. For example, let's say we have a variable `$abc = 0;`. Now if we just provide the variable in the condition as `if ($abc)`, it will not work, as `if (0)` doesn't satisfy the condition. So, in this case, we will need to use `if (isset($abc))` to successfully pass the condition.

Comment: Huh? `0` won't satisfy `!empty` though, so it's entirely pointless.

Comment: That's why I normally use this pair - `isset() && !empty()`. :)

Comment: And that's completely pointless. :) `!empty($foo)` is equivalent to `isset($foo) && $foo` (`empty($foo)` is equivalent to `!isset($foo) || !$foo`). So you're really writing `isset($foo) && isset($foo) && $foo`, which also doesn't work if `$foo` is `0`.

Comment: @deceze - ok, no issues; I will surely brush up the basics of what `empty()` actually does. But many thanks for pointing me that issue.

Answer (score 2):

Your form input's name is "search" not "submitSearchSimple".

The id is not passed to the server and neither is anything that isn't a form control (like the anchor in your example).

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to identify what variable you passed as POST : you could have done a *var_dump($_POST)* in your *profiles.php*.
You would have seen

> array(1) { ["search"]=>  string(4) "test" }

Therefore, you could have seen that it wasn't $_POST["s"] but $_POST["search"] and concluded that it wasn't the *id* that gives the name of the index but the *name*.

I don't see the point of using javascript in this case... (well, i can imagine it's for css styling, but you can easily style a submit button anyway.